# How to associate a filetype to a desktop entry correctly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mime-types, xdgutils

I'm try to associate my custom filetype with my app, which is an electron appimage. My filetype seems to be correctly registered, xdg-mime seems good, but xdg-open doesn't know how to open it.

I've created an MyApp-MyFile.xml, installed by doing:

```
$ xdg-mime installMyApp-MyExt.xml
```

When I query filetype of my file everything seems good:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype foo.myext
application/x-myapp

$ xdg-mime query default application/x-myapp
appimagekit-myapp.desktop
```

The desktop file is automatically generated from electron build option, and automatically installed when the appimage is launched.

```
$ cat ~/.local/share/applications/appimagekit-myapp.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyApp
Comment=MyApp main application
Exec="/home/full/path/MyApp.AppImage" %U
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=appimagekit-myapp
StartupWMClass=MyApp
X-AppImage-Version=X.X.X
Version=1.0
MimeType=text/html;application/x-myapp;
Categories=Utility;
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=3
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
X-AppImage-BuildId=1Nj1YJAtgORaUJWan9BoWfD5r2q
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.23
X-AppImage-Comment=Generated by /tmp/.mount_MyAppLXHZ7ue/AppRun
TryExec=/home/full/path/MyApp.AppImage
```

Despite all that `xdg-open foo.myext` doesn't found an app to opens the file.

I find out that `mimeopen foo.myext` open my app, but without passing args correctly. That's nice but I need to fix xdg-open

My OS is ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: I believe your app must be on-path and `appimagekit-myapp.desktop` needs to be executable. Please show the permissions on the file. Also see [this directory listing](https://pastebin.com/A4zFgdjc), which is a Desktop with four shortcuts that work as expected. There are usually lots of sample shortcuts in `/usr/share`. Just about every UI application has one. Perform `find /usr/share/ -name '*.desktop'`.

Comment: It's a path error. My appImage is named `MyApp version.appImage`. The space between the app name and the version number is not properly escaped at some point. Thanks for your tips !